# Why does definite integral not depend on the variable?

Tags: calculus, integration

Why does definite integration not depend on the variable ?? If I can use any other variable which is defined in such a way that It lies outside of the given interval, then the expression for intergral may vary.

Can you give me a mathematical proof to it(ie not just examples)

Comment: I assume you mean it doesnt depend on the variable you are integrating against

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what is called a bound variable.
We have $$\int_a^b f(x) \,\mathrm dx=\int_a^b f(t) \,\mathrm dt$$ just like we have $$\forall n\in\mathbb N\colon n^2\ge n\iff \forall k\in\mathbb N\colon k^2\ge k$$ or just like the correct answer to

> What is $3x$ if $x=4$?

is the same as to

> What is $3u$ if $u=4$?

As others have said, all this is more or less by definition. But you can give a proof for integrals using sustitution with the identity function if you desire, though that merely hide a direct proof from the definition that was used for showing the rule of substitution.

As a matter of fact, in measure theory there is a notation 
$$\int f\,\mathrm d\mu$$
for integrals that does *not* make use of a variable for the argument, and this makes it more obvious that we are using the function $f$ "as a whole" and not specific values $f(x)$ (or $f(t)$) when integrating.

Comment: I'm accustomed to the term "dummy" myself. That is, it doesn't really matter what variable you use (e.g. $\int_a^b f(u)\,\mathrm du=\int_a^b f(v)\,\mathrm dv$), except maybe it is poor form to use $d$ as the dummy. ;)

Answer (score 0):

why don't you give us an example of what you mean? No integral should depend on the variable you integrate against. $\int f(x) dx$  is a short hand $\int^x f(y) dy$ where the lower boundary is not given and can be chosen arbitarily, hence the +C

Comment: Well, if I have u substitution, can I just substitute x in whatever simplified function I get after u substitution without using the equation that tells me how u and x are related?

Comment: @SaurabhRaje I don't understand what you just said, you need to give an example.

Answer (score 0):

A definite integral works like this: you pick a function and you get a number. That's all. Of course you need to make things precise (the domain of the function must include the interval of integration, the function must have some properties etc.), but a definite integral is a machinery that produces a number (either real or complex, in some cases).
Therefore it is meaningless to ask for a proof: you cannot prove a definition!